# File upload testing using unit test python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a python function which basically uploads a file from a directory that got from user's input. I would like to write a test for it but could not find a way to do it using unit test. Could you please help me with this?

My function is:

```
def scene_upload(self):
    filename_scene = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file")
    print(filename_scene)
    with open(filename_scene, newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        line_count = 0
        for row in csv_reader:
            if line_count == 0:
                line_count += 1
            else:
                self.time_stamp.append(int(row[0]))
                self.active_func.append(int(row[1]))
                self.active_func_output.append(row[2])
                self.dstream_func.append(int(row[3]))
                self.dstream_func_aspect.append(row[4])
                self.time_tolerance.append(row[5])
                line_count += 1
```

Comment: `scene_upload` should take a filename as an argument; push the call to `askopenfilename` as far towards the "edge" of your code as possible.

Comment: Otherwise, what are you having trouble with? Calling the function on an object will update that object's state, so you just create an object, call the method with a known file, then verify the object's state against what you expect given the file you provided.

Comment: I got what you meant. I was confused because I put the asking for the directory into my function. I put it out of the function and put the derived filename_scene into the function as an argument and that worked.Thanks so much for the advice!

Comment: Actually, better yet, take an argument that can be passed directly to `csv.reader` as an argument, and let the caller be responsible for opening the file. Then your test case an use something as simple as list as the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by rewriting the method to take an iterable as an argument:

```
def scene_upload(self, scene):        
    csv_reader = csv.reader(scene, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    next(csv_reader)  # Skip the header
    for line_count, row in enumerate(csv_reader, 1):
        self.time_stamp.append(int(row[0]))
        self.active_func.append(int(row[1]))
        self.active_func_output.append(row[2])
        self.dstream_func.append(int(row[3]))
        self.dstream_func_aspect.append(row[4])
        self.time_tolerance.append(row[5])
```

In production use, you make the caller responsible for opening the file:

```
filename_scene = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file")
print(filename_scene)
with open(filename_scene, newline='') as csv_file:
    x.scene_upload(csv_file)
```

In tests, though, you can pass a simple list of strings as your test data.

```
def test_upload(self):
    test_data = ["header", "1,2,foo,4,bar,baz"]
    x = MyClass()
    x.scene_upload(test_data)
    self.assertEqual(x.time_stamp, [1])
    self.assertEqual(x.active_func, [2])
    # etc
```